# How to add non editable word “ I want ” in contact form 7 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, contact-form-7, contact-form, elementor

I want to add “I want” word to contact form 7 in wordpress(not a placeholder*), which is non editable for user while sending query

How to do that? anyone know about this?
please give me a solution
[image]

Please check this image

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a straightforward solution. Just make the placeholder titles.

So it would state "I want" above and you could replace the placeholders with something like **"Type what you want here..." or "Type here..."**